# Django distinct group by query on two fields

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I have a model which have 2 fields.

```
class MyModel:
   tcode = Charfield
   created_on = Date field
   #some more fields
```

now this model can have multiple rows with same tcode, and each row can have different day or same.

e.g.

```
tcode1, 1/2/2001
tcode2, 1/2/2001
tcode2, 2/2/2001
....etc.
```

I want to filter query on this model such that tcode and date field combination should be unique. how can I get all those objects.

i was trying to do this

`MyModel.objects.all().order_by('tcode').distinct('tcode', 'created_on')`

Now you may ask that in case if there are two rows with same data in two fields which one row I want! it doesn't matter to me, any row would work fine.

Comment: What sql are you using? `distinct()` with positional arguments `(*fields)` will work only on PostgreSQL. Try `MyModel.objects.all().order_by('tcode').distinct()`

Comment: Then `MyModel.objects.all().order_by('tcode').distinct('tcode', 'created_on')` surely will not work. Have you tried to use `distinct()` without positional arguments?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't think there's one single query that could do this, because there's no mechanism from database to pick random one from duplicates. However, if you only care about those two fields, you could do:

```
MyModel.objects.order_by('tcode').values('tcode', 'created_on').distinct()
```

This won't give you complete `MyModel` objects, but a list of dictionaries that contain all the existing combinations of `tcode` and `created_on`.

Answer (score 17):

Today I faced the same problem. In Django admin in get_queryset method I needed to make the distinct operation in multiple fields. I solved this problem this way:

```
from django.db.models import TextField
from django.db.models.functions import Concat
Mymodel.objects.filter(...).annotate(distinct_name=Concat('tcode', 'created_on', output_field=TextField())).order_by('distinct_name').distinct('distinct_name')
```

This decision helps to return QuerySet with ID of the record

Comment: this works well with PostgreSQL but not with MySQL database