# How to get unique values with id in django from database

Tags: python, django

So this is my query and it displays only file name but I want 'id' also.

```
filenames=Upload.objects.values('file').distinct().filter(created_by=request.user).all()
```

this will generate only unique files as dict. But I want 'id' of those files also and if use 'id' inside that 'values' it will not give unique file names. So this is my issue. I'm okay with other methods as well to solve this issue.

Comment: Try distinct for `file` field

Comment: i'm doing the same thing there.

Comment: Are you using Postgresql for your application? And there are something you have to follow when you want to query distinct data on specific field, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct . Make sure that you added `order_by` into your query code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django distinct group by query on two fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33088337/django-distinct-group-by-query-on-two-fields)

Comment: I'm using sqlite.

Comment: @wfehr if use query like that, then it will not give unique values.

Comment: @SharathNayak you can test my answer it will surely work

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
from django.db.models import F

Upload.objects.filter(created_by=request.user).values('file').distinct().annotate(id=F('pk'))
```

Comment: Sure. Will try it out.

Comment: I'm getting all values.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think we can achieve it using `Distinct`.

So I used loop like this.

```
filenames=Upload.objects.filter(created_by=request.user).all()
seen = set()
result = []
for f in filenames:
    if f.file not in seen:
        result.append(f)
        seen.add(f.file)
print result
```